# Help me understand what man says in the video

Tags: pronunciation

In [this clip](http://www.spoilertv.com/2014/11/the-originals-episode-208-brothers-that_82.html) staring on about **00:21** sec, Elijah says:

> Yes, **...** the most human of experiences.

Can't understand what words is he pronouncing in the place of three dots. Pleas, help me, I really have trouble with understanding British accent.

Thanks to all of those who help people here. :)

Comment: some would argue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

He says:

> Yes, some would argue the most human of experiences.